# C#: How can I remove the scrollbars from the mdi parent?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Well I just finished checking through the few related questions and one seemed to have the answer but the link is broken and the other wasnt very well stated.

I'm merely trying to remove the scrollbars on the mdi parent when a child is moved outside the parent's bounds.

http://img224.imageshack.us/img224/4788/mdiscrollbars.jpg

What I'm trying to accomplish is to reproduce menus that can appear within mmo's that you can move around and off the screen. I assumed it was with multiple forms but if I'm wrong or I'm doing it the hard way, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/819be1ea-b43f-447c-bb01-bf07ce36dcde) which uses interop.

The link also shows how to prevent a child form from moving beyond the mdi parent's borders.

The code provided in the link does the trick, but you'll have to add the following using directive:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

As mentioned in the linked thread, there is a bit of a flicker but you might want to try it out.

Answer (score -1):

It is easier way to do it and without flicking. Look at this:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg != 3)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
```